# How tu use PerspectiveAPI in Java?

Tags: java, api, http, request, perspective

how to use the [perspective api](https://github.com/conversationai/perspectiveapi/blob/master/1-get-started/sample.md), in java, I have tried several codes and it does not work too much .

I have do this, but not work.

`

```
try {
  String url = "https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1alpha1&", key = "key=my_key";

    final URL serverUrl = new URL(url + key);
        URLConnection urlConnection = serverUrl.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        BufferedWriter httpRequestBodyWriter = new BufferedWriter(new
                OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream()));
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("{\"comment\": {\"text\": \"" + "Salut mec" + "\"},"
                + "\"requestedAttributes\": {\"TOXICITY\": {}}}");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.flush();
        httpRequestBodyWriter.close();
        System.out.println("CODE : " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
        
        BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((httpConnection.getInputStream())));
        String output;
        while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(output);
        }
        httpConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

I have Code 404, and `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1alpha1&key=my_key`

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Well, a 404 indicates the url is wrong. My guess would be that you need to provide something other than `$discovery` because that looks like a placeholder to me. Note that the link you've provided lists that url in an example that uses some NodeJS library so this library might as well replace that placeholder. Since you're doing it directly from Java you need to find out what the correct thing to do would be (e.g. have a look at the curl example and the api documentation)

Comment: Thanks you, taht work ! I replace the url to https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze?&